# VBA Conditional Replace

Tags: vba

I can't figure out on my own how to do this. 
I have two columns and I want to replace data in the second column but only when the value from column 1 y not the same as in the column 2.

Column 1 
Panda
Bear
Ant
etc.

Column 2
Bear
Panda
Bear
Wolf
Ant
Jellyfish

What I want to achieve is:

If A1 <> B1 then replace "Bear" with "Mammal"
and so on.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Find the last row in the column 1 , set a range from first to lastrow , loop that range and if currentcell <> currentcell.offset( ,1) then replace.....

Answer (score 0):

This is an example, change as appropriate. I am a little uncertain about your replace statement. I have coded as you have written but am wondering if you have a set list of replacements?

Code below follows logic of my comment.

```
Sub test()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim wsSource As Worksheet

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set wsSource = wb.Worksheets("Sheet4") 'change as appropriate

Dim lastRowColA As Long

lastRowColA = wsSource.Cells(wsSource.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Dim loopRange As Range

Set loopRange = wsSource.Range("A1:A" & lastRowColA)

Dim currCell As Range

For Each currCell In loopRange

    If currCell <> currCell.Offset(, 1) Then

        currCell.Offset(, 1) = Replace(currCell.Offset(, 1), "Bear", "Mammal")

    End If

Next currCell

End Sub
```